# Is Azure client ID world wide unique?

Tags: azure, clientid

I have a database table with [Azure App registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app). These apps are added across different tenants.

I would like to know I can use the application id (client id) of Azure app as the primary key of the table.

Is the client ID world wide unique?

Comment: That's what the G in GUID means....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** it is.If you look at Official document for [`application property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta#properties)

Application Id (GUID) break down like this:

- 60 bits of timestamp
- 48 bits of computer identifier
- 14 bits ofuniquifier
- six bits are fixed,